# Connecting to MS SQL Server Hosted on a Web Hosting site

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell

It's the first time I am trying to connect to SQL Server which is hosted on a Web hosting site. 
All I have is: IP Address of Database Machine, Initial Catalog, User ID & Password.

I tried to connect using these but was not successful.

I tried below code:

```psh
$ConnString = Server=xxx.xx.xx.xx,1433;Database=DBNAME;uid=USERID;pwd=Password;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $ConnString
$connection.Open()
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query

$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
$table.Load($result)

$connection.Close()
```

I get below error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)"

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure this web host allows remote connections to the DB's ?

Comment: Your connection string is lacking an opening double quote. Was that omitted just in this question, or is it missing in your script as well?

Comment: It got missed while I was posting the question here. Syntax wise everything is OK. I checked it...

Comment: @sodawillow I am not very sure on this thing. I'll check today. Thanks!

Comment: Then please fix the code in your question.